# Replacing items in a list

Tags: python, list, replace

I am trying to replace items in a list based on sub-string match

I've the following list

```
x = ['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']
```

If there are two items e.g. D-cat and cat, I want to replace the item with prefix by the item without a prefix.
i.e. D-cat has to be replaced with cat. Likewise , I want to replace 
all prefix-xxx with xxx.

I tired the following using `replace`.

```
x = [animal.replace('D-cat','cat') for animal in x]
```

Expected result:

```
x = ['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
```

I'm not sure how this can be implemented for all items.

I'd like to ask for some suggestions.

EDIT: 
Test case

```
x =['C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```

expected output:

```
x=['Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```

Comment: Are the two items always one after the other? What do you want to prefix in-case of `R-rat` and `S-rat`? What if there was also just `rat` after?

Comment: I see now you also have `L-cat` but ignore it, so I guess it is consecutive items?

Comment: and post the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid double looping I would pass once to hash animals with no prefix, and then replace:

```
#Assuming no one letter animal. 
#The condition allows for animals with '-' 
#in the name by insisting '-'  not be the second character.
#('-' in a) would not have allowed '-' in the name.
animal_set = set(a for a in x if a[1] != '-')
for i in range(len(x)):
    animal = x[i].split('-',1)[-1]
    if animal in animal_set: x[i]= animal
```

I think this is better then insisting on a comprehension and the speed will matter for long lists (n^2 compared to n complexity). This includes using `in` operator on the original list.

I would also say there is absolutely no use for a regular expression in solution you choose - regular splitting or indexing of a string would work here. If you really want a one liner for the loop you could use:

```
[a.split('-',1)[-1] if a.split('-',1)[-1] in animal_set else a for a in x]
```

but now you would have to split twice instead of once, so I would be against this.

Note also the "1" I pass to split - this will handle extra dashes such as L-complex-animal, splitting them to "L" and "complex-animal".

Comment: the code works for the input in my original post. However, `'C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit'` this test case fails. Expected result `'Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit'`

Comment: @Natasha that == should be a != in the first line, my bad.

Comment: Excellent! would it be possible to do this? `['eta-C-Rab 6-bit', 'C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']`  expected output: `['Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit'] `

Comment: @Natasha That warrants a new question. In your original question the prefix was always a single letter (`S,R,C`). `eta-C` is 4 a character letter word which even includes a dash. You would need to specify how do you know if something is a prefix or part of the name - which will change the question too much.

Comment: If you do end up asking a new question, make sure to give a **full** sample of the list, explain how you determine if an item in the list is a name (with no prefix), and you can link to it in the comments here and I'll take a look (and others stopping by).

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with basic for loop:

```
mylist = ['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in range(len(mylist)):
        if mylist[j] in mylist[i]:
            mylist[i] = mylist[j]

print (mylist)
```

output:

```
['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
```

EDIT: Test case

```
mylist = ['C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
ouput >> ['Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```

Comment: not sure if it matters, but the difference between this and the regex approach is this is not checking what the prefix looks like - it would do the substitution for 'my-little-rabbit' or 'jack-rabbit' or '-rabbit'.

Comment: @Stael That is easily solved by passing a second parameter "1" to `split`. regex is way overkill for this type of string manipulation.

Comment: @ncica fails for the test case posted in the edit of the original post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` for a faster check if an prefix-less animal exists in your list.

```
x = ["D-cat", "cat", "C-Rabbit", "Rabbit", "R-rat", "S-rat", "L-cat", "C-Rab 6-bit", "Rab 6-bit"]
x_set = set(x)

processed_animals = []
for animal in x:
    no_prefix_animal = animal.split("-", 1)[-1]
    if no_prefix_animal in x_set:
        animal = no_prefix_animal

    processed_animals.append(animal)

print(processed_animals)
# ['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat', 'Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the desired word and the prefix are hyphen-separated and the hyphen does not appear in either the prefix or the word, this might work:

```
 lookup_dict = {animal:True for animal in x if '-' not in animal}

 def get_word(animal):
     without_prefix = animal.split('-')[-1]
     return without_prefix if lookup_dict.get(without_prefix) else animal

 x = [get_word(animal) for animal in x]
```

Note: A more generic approach would be to use a regular expression. This approach, although specific, is much efficient in comparison to using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

With simple list comprehension and `str.find` function:

```
x = ['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']
res = [s[s.find('-')+1:]
       if ('-' in s and s[s.find('-')+1:] in x) else s for s in x[:]]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 0):

for fans of one liners (not necessarily recommended):

```
x = ['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']
[re.sub('\w-', '', i) if re.sub('\w-', '', i) in x else i for i in x]

# ['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `itertools.groupby`:

```
x = ['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']

from itertools import groupby

out = []
s = sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda k: (k[1].split()[0].split('-', maxsplit=1)[-1], len(k[1])))
for v, g in groupby(s, lambda k: k[1].split()[0].split('-', maxsplit=1)[-1]):
    l = [*g]
    remove_prefix = not '-' in l[0][-1].split()[0]
    to_replace = l[0][-1]
    out.extend([(i[0],to_replace) if remove_prefix else i for i in l])

print([i[1] for i in sorted(out)])
```

Prints:

```
['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
```

Test case with `x = ['C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']` prints:

```
['Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` with a list comprehension:

```
import re
def _strip(x):
  return [re.sub('^[A-Z]\-', '', a) if any(a.endswith(c) and not re.findall('^[A-Z]\-', c) for c in x) \
          else a for i, a in enumerate(x)]

print(_strip(['D-cat', 'cat', 'C-Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'L-cat']))
print(_strip(['C-Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']))
```

Output:

```
['cat', 'cat', 'Rabbit', 'Rabbit', 'R-rat', 'S-rat', 'cat']
['Rab 6-bit', 'Rab 6-bit']
```